# c# cannot implicitly convert type string [] to string

Tags: c#, string

i tried to split the answer from the question in my quiz generator, here is my code

```
string test = questions = objReader.ReadLine().Split('?');

questions[qCounter] = questions[0];
answers[qCounter] = questions[1];
qCounter++;
```

Comment: Where is `qCounter` defined? Where is `answers` defined? Your question is incomplete. Also, `Split` returns a `string[]`, but you're trying to assign it to a `string` (which is what the error message is telling you)

Comment: Also the double assignment on the first line is a bit confusing, especially for someone relatively inexperienced. It would have been easier to debug if this was broken into two lines eg `questions = objReader.ReadLine().Split('?');` then `string test = questions;` which would have made it easier to see that `questions` is an array of strings, which can't directly be assigned the single string variable `test`

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong because when you split a string, it return an array of string

```
string test = questions = objReader.ReadLine().Split('?');
```

then you should to do this:

```
string[] test = questions = objReader.ReadLine().Split('?');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the message is clear enough to identify the issue, as it says cannot implicitly convert type `string []` to `string`. which means you are trying to assing a `string[]` to a string object. yes exactly that you did there.

The output of `.Split()` is a `string[]`(RHS of the assignment), and the variable `test` is of type string. So its better to change the type of `test` as well as `questions` to `string[]` like the following:

```
string[] questions ;
string[] test = questions = objReader.ReadLine().Split('?');
```